# How to deploy Angular app to CentOS out of Grunt?

Tags: linux, angularjs, deployment, centos, gruntjs

Is it possible to 1-click deploy such as "grunt deploy" to CentOS server? (Digital Ocean dropplet) For web server uses Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

angularjs project is simple static files.
so you can create grunt task for build production ready archive and upload it to server.
nginx should be preconfigured.
also will nice compress all text files(js, css, html)